# mocking bean not always works

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I encounter a strange behavior in my junit testings.
For some tests i need to mock a microservice client bean.
I use BDDMockito.given to simulate the microservice response.
When i run "all tests" in IntelliJ tests that use this fails because the client trys to load from the microservice.
When I rerun those failed tests, it works.

I tried to launch custom selected tests I can't find another test that produce those tests to fail.

Could this be the number of tests (500+) that produces this behavior?

```
@MockBean
protected FileserverClient fileserverClient;

@Before
public void initMockBeans(){
    given(fileserverClient.createFrom64(any(File64.class)))
        .willReturn(FileCreatorForTest.createFile());
}
```

### EDIT

the error here:
It's trying to connect to my consul to get a route to my microservice. It doesn't have to because the FeignClient is supposed to have been mocked.

```
2018-02-07 14:52:58.325  WARN 22665 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'retryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.HttpClientRibbonConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'retryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonLoadBalancer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.loadbalancer.ILoadBalancer]: Factory method 'ribbonLoadBalancer' threw exception; nested exception is com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8500 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connexion refusée (Connection refused)
2018-02-07 14:52:58.333 ERROR 22665 --- [           main] o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Internal Server Error
```

I try to lauch all tests files except one, it works. I select the excluded one and disable another it works (i played this game a long time to try to find a test file that could cause this).

Exemple code of a potential failing test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MeetingApp.class,SecurityBeanOverrideConfiguration.class})
public class MeetingRoomResourceIntTest extends BaseResourceTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        final MeetingRoomResource meetingRoomResource = new MeetingRoomResource(meetingRoomService, meetingRoomQueryService);
        this.restMeetingRoomMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(meetingRoomResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setConversionService(createFormattingConversionService())
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
    }
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createMeetingRoom() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = meetingRoomRepository.findAll().size();
        // Create the MeetingRoom
        MeetingRoomDTO meetingRoomDTO = meetingRoomMapper.toDto(meetingRoom);
        meetingRoomDTO.setFile64(FileCreatorForTest.createFile64());
        restMeetingRoomMockMvc.perform(post("/api/meeting-rooms")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(meetingRoomDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // Validate the MeetingRoom in the database
        List<MeetingRoom> meetingRoomList =     meetingRoomRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(meetingRoomList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
        MeetingRoom testMeetingRoom = meetingRoomList.get(meetingRoomList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getMdLocationId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_MD_LOCATION_ID);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getFspictureId()).isEqualTo(FileCreatorForTest.DEFAULT_FS_PICTURE_ID.intValue());
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_NAME);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getDescription()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getCapacity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.isNaturalDayLight()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_NATURAL_DAY_LIGHT);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.isPamFriendly()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_PAM_FRIENDLY);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getStars()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_STARS);
        assertThat(testMeetingRoom.getWrapUpTime()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_TIME);
    }
}
```

And my BaseResourceTest:

```
public abstract class BaseResourceTest
{

    @MockBean
    protected FileserverClient fileserverClient;

    public BaseResourceTest()
    {
        MyCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.forceTenantId("junit");
    }

    @Before
    public void initMockBeans(){
        given(fileserverClient.createFrom64(any(File64.class)))
        .willReturn(FileCreatorForTest.createFile());

    }
}
```

### EDIT 2

The client is used inside a EntityListener component and set staticly. Could this could cause the instability ?

```
@Component
public class FileServerDependantListener {


    private Logger logger;

    static private FileserverClient fileserverClient;

    private AbstractFileServerDependantEntity entity;

    public FileServerDependantListener() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(FileServerDependantListener.class.getName());

    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(FileserverClient fileserverClient){
        FileServerDependantListener.fileserverClient = fileserverClient;

    }

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void preCommit(AbstractFileServerDependantEntity entity){
        if (entity.getFile64() != null)  {
            entity.getFile64().setFileType(entity.getFileType());
            File file = fileserverClient.createFrom64(entity.getFile64());
            entity.setFsPictureId(file.getId());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And also can you post code of your test class with the class annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application contexts of your tests might be being shared between tests when running them all together in IntelliJ. This can cause problems if parts of the context are affected by the tests themselves or even the loading of the context.

You can try annotate all your test classes with `@DirtiesContext` to ensure a fresh application context is loaded for every test class. This annotation can also be used at method level on your `@Test` methods if required.

Comment: It works but slowing down testing. I'll use it to isolate wich tests "dirtifies" the context.